# How to combine QUARTILE.INC, IF, and OR

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to combine QUARTILE.INC, IF and OR. I tried to find 25 percentile with the formula below, but it seems not working well.
`=QUARTILE.INC(IF(OR($C$1:$C$140=K3,$D$1:$D$140=K3,$E$1:$E$140=K3),$B$1:$B$140),1)`

So, I want to find the 25 percentile of column B where the data on either of column C or D or E is K3. The image of the data set is inserted below;

[image of the data on excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LJr5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your Formula, if I consider the Syntax of the Command. **The basic problem is the BLANK CELLs in Column D & E.**

Below is the Formula I've tested, calculates the Quartile, but as soon I replace any value with BLANK Cell, produces ZERO as result.

```
=QUARTILE.INC(IF(OR($B$75:$B$80=5,$C$75:$C$80=2,$D$75:$D$80=5),$E$75:$E$80),1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! So, I converted all the blank cell into 0, and tried my formula again. But it still returned 0.... do you have any idea?? thanks for taking your time.
'=QUARTILE.INC(IF(OR($C$1:$C$140=K3,$D$1:$D$140=K3,$E$1:$E$140=K3),$B$1:$B$140),1)'

Comment: Check first whether all the Data Ranges Matching with K3 or not, also suppose K3 is 10 and possible any of the Ranges doesn't has 10, in this case also Formula produces Zero, or to cross check write the Formula without Criteria. Like =Quartile.Inc(B1:B10,1). If this produces answer  other than Zero means, K3 doesn't matches with any of the Data Ranges.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! I could fix the problem!

Comment: Nice to here from you,, keep asking.